# Certbot Timeouts

Tags: timeout, lets-encrypt, certbot

Can someone provide me a checklist of things to have set so certbot can issue me a letsencrypt SSL? I can't get it to verify and it times out.

I can access through the domain name. Both on http and https. So I know the virtual host file is setup correctly. And I know it's not a firewall or dns issue either.

I'm not using a .htaccess folder or anything, just an empty directory with an hello world index.

Directory permissions are set to 777

I can't think of what else to check?

Comment: can you share the certbot cli response as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue to my problem, it wasn't anything configured on the machine but it was an issue with my DNS configuration. I had a A record to my IPv4 address as well as a AAA record to my IPv6 address which was causing issues. The resolution was to get rid of one of them and after that the certification went smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

You need (from sources)

- The Webroot method requires HTTP on port 80 for Certbot to validate.
- The Server Name must match that of it's corresponding DNS.
- Permissions may need to be altered on the host to allow read-access to http://domain.tld/.well-known.

How I've created and configured Certbot, SSL Cert and Nginx :

**Command to create the certs**

```
certbot certonly --webroot \  
--webroot-path /usr/share/nginx/html \
--renew-by-default -d <YOUR_HOST_NAME.COM> \
--config-dir ~/.certbot/config \
--logs-dir ~/.certbot/logs \
--work-dir ~/.certbot/work
```

In my nginx conf,

```
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {  
    allow all;
    root /var/lib/letsencrypt/;
    default_type "text/plain";
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

In Apache, create a new file

> /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-acme.conf

```
Alias /.well-known/acme-challenge/ "/var/lib/letsencrypt/.well-known/acme-challenge/"
<Directory "/var/lib/letsencrypt/">
    AllowOverride None
    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
    Require method GET POST OPTIONS
</Directory>
```

and include in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

References

- Wiki -> [Let’s Encrypt - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Let%E2%80%99s_Encrypt#Mapping_ACME-challenge_requests)
- Blog -> [Get an Opensource SSL Certificate from letsencrypt.org and use in Nginx](https://www.trymuffin.in/get-an-opensource-ssl-certificate-from-letsencrypt-org/)